# php response is not sent before the script ends

Tags: php, ajax, flush

I issue an ajax post method to send commands to the php backend. One one these is a "reboot". I'm trying to get the answer back before the script ends:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

switch ($obj->{'action'}) {
  case "reboot":
    $data = '{"success" : true}';

    ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    exec("sudo reboot");
    break;

  default:
    $data = '{"success": "fail"}';
    break;
}
```

The ajax call (on client side) times out and never receives the answer.
Of course I can add a small delay to the reboot command, but I want to understand why my code is not working.

I'm running it on an RPi with lighttpd and fast-cgi.

Comment: It will be better if you do not call your "reboot" from here. Do everything else, return to your ajax callback, and from inside the callback, call another php function via ajax that reboots. Plus, as far as I know, you cannot issue "system" command from browser based php function call.

Comment: Actually it works... I granted to `www-data` the sudo privileges for reboot and halt. Anyway your "workaround" is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cron job which will run on every second and check for some setting, a reboot or something of the like. If that's true, a reboot is issued. The script issued by your AJAX call could set this setting to true so the script can respond to the client-side. When the server is rebooted, the reboot setting could be automatically set back to false. But this seems to be an extremely unsafe approach, since any user might be able to send such a request, rendering your server unusable.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But my question is not about different methods, indeed I'm interested to understand WHY my code doesn't work. It should flush the response before rebooting.